# What is the difference between 'I like cleaning up' and 'I like cleanups'?

Tags: grammar

I like clean up or cleanup. Is this a correct sentence?

How would it differ from I like cleaning up or I like cleanups?

Simple example sentences and context would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but not I like to clean up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I like cleanup

"I like cleanup" is a valid sentence. *Cleanup* is a noun that means the act of cleaning, or a session of cleaning.

However, without context it might not very clear what you mean. Here are some examples where it would be clear in context:

- In a workplace where employees are assigned to clean the area every day at a certain time: "I like cleanup" would mean you enjoy that part of your workday. It would be clear to your coworkers what you meant since they share this context.
- If your town is having a community park cleaning event: "I like this cleanup. It makes our town nicer and I got to know several neighbors.

### I like cleaning up

If you said this to me, I would assume you like to keep your home or workplace tidy, and that you enjoy the activity of cleaning.

### I like cleanups

Again, this is kind of ambiguous without context, but in general it would mean that you like cleanup sessions or events.

Answer (score 3):

agree with Aaron, The sentence seem incomplete to me also and need some context. For e.g:

> I like cleaning up my room on every weekend.
>
> I like a face cleanup before I take a face massage.
>
> I clean up my hands before I eat or cook.
>
> I like various cleanups available at massage parlor like fruit
>   cleanup, dry skin cleanup and oily skin cleanup etc.